# ggplot2: Turn off guide on one layer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot two layers in a plot -- a bar and a text layer. The bar and text layer are constructed from mutually exclusive slices of a `data.frame`. The slices are defined by the values of a categorical variable, `Category` below.

Now, for the text layer, I do not want the guide to be shown. In order to achieve this I:

1. Use `droplevels` to make sure that the redundant factor level (`Difference`) is not used in the `geom_bar`, and
2. That `show_guide = FALSE` for `geom_text`

However, I still get the guide for the omitted level for the layer where the level is omitted.

Here is an MWE that demonstrates the problem:

```
dfX = data_frame(
  id = rep.int(1:10, 3),
  Category = factor(rep(c("All", "Other", "Difference"), each = 10)), 
           Value = c(rpois(20, 10), abs(runif(10))*100))

ggplot(data = droplevels(subset(dfX, !Category %in% "Difference")), 
       aes(x = as.factor(id), y = Value, fill = Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  geom_text(data = droplevels(subset(dfX, Category %in% "Difference")), 
            aes(y = 10, label = signif(Value, 0)), 
            show_guide = FALSE) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

I do not want the highlighted level in the legend -- how can I achieve this?

Comment: Your problem is inheritance between layers. You should probably only put the data in each specific layer. Alternatively, unmapping `fill` in `geom_text` works for me.

Comment: @joran Thanks, what is inherited (passed around?) between layers -- `fill`? What do you mean by only put the data in each specific layer? My understanding is that that is what I am doing.

Comment: You pass data and aesthetics in the top level `ggplot()` call. All of this is passed on to _every_ layer, unless specifically overridden. The shortest solution is to include `fill = NULL` inside of `aes()` in the `geom_text` layer.

Comment: @joran Thanks, resetting `fill` works in this example, but not on my slightly more complex actual setup. Let me try to figure out why -- else I will update this example.

Comment: @joran Ok, works. Make it an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unmap the `fill` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(data = droplevels(subset(dfX, !Category %in% "Difference")), 
             aes(x = as.factor(id), y = Value, fill = Category)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
    geom_text(data = droplevels(subset(dfX, Category %in% "Difference")), 
                        aes(y = 10, label = signif(Value, 0),fill = NULL), 
                        show_guide = FALSE) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```